# How to determine Number of AMPs and Nodes required in Teradata?

Tags: nodes, teradata

One of my company's Teradata Database has 6 Nodes and each node carry 24 AMPs.
Could any one please let me know how to determine how many number of AMPs are required per node?

> If more AMPs / Nodes are supposed to increase performance, why is it not true to have maximum number of AMPs / Nodes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of AMPs per node is determined by the available CPU and IO.

Usually it's approx. 1 AMP per logical CPU and each AMP has assigned 2*2 mirrored (RAID1) disks (plus eventually a 1/4 of a SSD).

Simply adding AMPs will not improve performance, because you need to add disks, too, and the system is already using 100% resources.

To get more AMPs you add a new node with new CPU/disks.

Comment: Thanks . could you please explain, what do you mean by `the system is already using 100% resources` in this scenario ? Also, expand SSD please

Comment: The system has been designed to fully utilize both CPU & IO, i.e. AMP/CPU/IO are balanced to avoid bottlenecks. Adding more AMPs to a node also means adding more disks/IO and then CPU will be a bottleneck. And SSD simply means Solid State Disks, which boost IO performance, most new system include those, approx. 15 % of the existing space on SSD vs. 85 % HDD